# Ansible using variables properly for uri request

Tags: json, ansible

Something is wrong with the way I am substituting values and constructing a json template in ansible to be sent via the `uri` module to a webserver. Can anyone assist?

It seems like ansible is converting all the double brackets in the json to single brackets when it is running the replace command

Full Example:
I have a variable file where I am storing secrets:

ie `secrets.yml`

```
---
username: "admin"
password: "admin"
```

I am reading these in and replace the values in a json template:
ie `template.json`

```
{
  "username": "***USERNAME_FIELD***",
  "password": "***PASSWORD_FIELD***"
}
```

the playbook has tasks structured thus

```
- name: load template
  set_fact:
    loginTemplate: "{{ lookup('file', 'template.json') }}"
   
- name: replace values with actuals
  set_fact:
    filledTemplate: "{{ loginTemplate |
    replace('***USERNAME_FIELD***', username) |
    replace('***PASSWORD_FIELD***', password) }}"

- name: submit request
  uri:
    url: "http://blah.com/api"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ filledTemplate }}"
    body_template: json
```

If I put the values in the json and just submit without the extra `set_fact` step to fill in the values it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the request body to json content using `to_json` filter in `set_fact`.

```yaml
- name: replace values with actuals
  set_fact:
    filledTemplate: "{{ loginTemplate |
      replace('***USERNAME_FIELD***', username) |
      replace('***PASSWORD_FIELD***', password) | to_json }}"
```

or in `uri` module,

```yaml
- name: submit request
  uri:
    url: "http://blah.com/api"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ filledTemplate | to_json }}"
    body_template: json
```

Also, are you missing `:` in the json file like?

```
{
  "username": "***USERNAME_FIELD***",
  "password": "***PASSWORD_FIELD***"
}
```

Comment: I noticed that I think ansible is converting all the double brackets in the json to single brackets

Comment: then try to convert the content using `to_json`, the first part of the answer and see.

Comment: `to_json` just adds double brackets around the whole thing